# How to add a website to Safari Top Sites manually?

Tags: safari

How to add a website to Safari Top Sites manually instead of viewing it so many times that Safari chose it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit your top sites and pin what do you want to see every time.

Comment: what if the website doesn't appear on it?

Comment: If you remove top sites you don't need, it'll show more sites you accessed last time.

Comment: @So Without viewing the website I want to add,I can't add them?

Comment: You can add them without viewing. Safari says at bottom "To add a page to Top Sites, drag its address (URL) to this window"

Comment: Er,sir,I still don't know how to drag.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's very simple, common and very useful action. You should type it somewhere (like address bar), select it, click with left button on it and move your mouse pointer to place you need still holding left button down. Just like moving files in Finder

Answer (score 6):

You can add it by dragging URL to top sites window.

[image]